# jquery length of text()

Tags: jquery, html

What's wrong with the below?

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id='test'>28</div>  
  </body>
</html>

<script>
$(document).ready(function (){
  if ($('#test').text().length() > 0) // error here?
   alert("test");
});
```

I get a JavaScript error in I.E 6 saying function expected on the line marked error.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Length in javascript is not a function. its a property so instead of length() use length

Answer (score 12):

**Many** things are wrong:

1. You didn't include jQuery in your page and you try to use functions from it
2. You didn't close your `script` tag
3. Your div is completely broken
4. You don't have a `DOCTYPE`
5. Your document doesn't have a `head` :-)
6. Your script is outside of the html
7. `length` is a property not a function

Comment: thanks point 7 the rest was quick mock up to show the scenario.

Answer (score 8):

`length` is **not a function**. it is a property.

```
'lol'.length === 3 // true
```

Answer (score 7):

You are looking for this function `.length` But you need to add the text value first before using `.length`.

Answer: `$("#test").val().length`

Answer (score 0):

beside the `length()`, there is another mistake

```
<div id='test')28</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't use JQuery to get length. Just use the standard javascript .length command.

There are a few functions that Javascript can handle without JQuery's help. (hyperbole intended)